# How to Display ACF Relationship Custom Field as Link to Specific Custom Post?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, permalinks, advanced-custom-fields

OK. I am reading this ACF tutorials, but I am not getting into this.

I have 2 post types: **Lists** and **Contacts**.

Every List must be related to some Contact, and I use **Relationship** custom field type (list_supplier), which is limited to only one choice (or Contact).

All I have to do is to **display link on Lists template as Title of Contact post** which is now related with that List.

Plugin
http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

**UPDATE:**

OK. I am close to solve this, but I have some problems with filter.

Here is the code I am using in my template:

```
 <?php $contacts = get_field('list_supplier'); ?>
                    <?php if( $contacts ): ?>
                        <?php foreach( $contacts as $contact ): ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $contact->ID ); ?>" target="blank"><?php echo get_the_title( $contact->ID ); ?></a>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

In one moment I make it work on front end, but there was some problem with filters.
When I [add some of these filters](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/tutorials/customize-the-relationship-field-list-query/) into functions.php, choices from custom field **list_supplier** disappear. When I remove filter **list_supplier** chioces are there, but they are not showing on front end.

I know that problem is in filter, but I dont know how to wrote it.

Comment: have you tried their example code? show us what code you have now.

Comment: Hi @Milo. Sorry because of the delay. I was posting answer :) Unfortunately, I delete all my working code because I couldn't make it work. There was one interesting snippet... I will try to wrote it again.

Comment: @Milo, I just make it work :) I will post update... Thank you any way. Cheers!

Comment: @Milo, please can you take a look on my code now. I am realy close to solve this. I think that I have problem with filters. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly, I make this working.

I put this in my template:

```
<?php $contacts = get_field('list_supplier'); ?>
<?php if( $contacts ): ?>
    <?php foreach( $contacts as $contact ): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $contact->ID ); ?>" target="blank"><?php echo get_the_title( $contact->ID ); ?></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And here is the filter I am using

```
<?php
function my_acf_load_field( $field )
{
    $field['choices'] = array(
        'custom' => 'My Custom Choice'
    );
    return $field;
}

// acf/load_field/key={$field_key} - filter for a specific field based on it's name
add_filter('acf/load_field/key=field_525c37d91ae8d', 'my_acf_load_field');
?>
```